# how to change voice with different modulation in android

Tags: android, voice, speech

i want to develop   talking app example like talking Tomcat  in android,but i have no idea for this concept any one guide for me.first i need how to change voice with different modulation and repeat voice any one help with me any tutorial and any code with greatly appreciated.